# Route of debug exceptions (like software step exception) in ARMv8

Tags: exception, arm64, hypervisor, armv8

In ARMv8 manual, it talks about the route of debug exceptions. However, it seems that the debug exceptions could only be route to EL1 or EL2. Is there any way to route the debug exceptions to EL3?

I am not familiar with EL2 (the hypervisor mode in ARMv7), may I use the EL2 without a real hypervisor? As the debug exceptions could be routed to EL2, can I just implement a simplest EL2 which traps to EL3 while handling the debug exceptions?

Comment: Why do you want your _firmware_ to have to know about debugging userspace?

Comment: From a quick scan of the ARM ARM, it doesn't appear possible to deliver a non-secure debug exception to EL3 from _anywhere_, which isn't all that surprising since as above it doesn't make much sense in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just trying to debug the system in EL3. I know normally we do this in EL1 or EL2, but the transparency may be great increased if we can do it in EL3.